# Ubuntu 22.04.1 doesn't find a proprietary Bluetooth driver for my laptop

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I have a hp pavilion 15 e009tu laptop. Bluetooth works fine on windows 10. Bluetooth not working on dual boot Ubuntu. Says... no Bluetooth found and asks me to insert dongle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pttas.jpg

Update : I did a search about my network card.**Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)**. Doesn't support bluetooth on Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3;lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I think there is a PPA for the driver